# why cumulative time in wincachegrind is so much higher than sum of the time?

Tags: php, cumulative-sum

Look at the picture below:

[image]

Cumulative time is 2,821 ms, but if you take a look at the functions if you get the sum of Total Cum. column it won't be that much high. Why is this happening? Does that time include my computer and browser lags?

**There is a time below the picture that says total self time is much lower:**

[image]

Comment: I know that when profiling PHP with tools such as xdebug the profiler itself can add additional overhead.  Is that accounted for?

Comment: @GordonM I noticed that Sum of total self time is 360ms. Is that what I should look for?